# Set the title background color of alert dialog without making a custome dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am using the alert dialog builder and I would like to change the default alert dialog title background color. I have done searches on it (but couldnt find what I want). The thing is that I don't want to create custom dialog and extend it as I want to use the existing functionality of alert dialog (setting items list ..etc).

Is there anyway I can set the title background color without having to create a custom dialog/add views to it .etc?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set custom title by using **setCustomTitle(view)**

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_view, null);
alert.setCustomTitle(view);
```

Comment: Great. Thank you. Accepted any idia how to do the same for dialog.l?this method does not exist for it

Comment: How are you creating dialog??......If you are creating dialog with Dialog class then I think you have to use custom layout by dialog.setContentView(int res) method and just remove your dialog title by dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)