# Android: How can I change AlertDialog Title Text Color and Background Color without using custom layout?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, background-color, textcolor

I want to change `AlertDialog` **title color** and **background color** without using custom layout. My requirement,

[image: I want like this]

I tried below code, but can't work.

```
final CharSequence[] items = {" Visiting Card", "Prescription Letter"};
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
            builder.setMessage(message)
            .setTitle(title).setCancelable(false);

    builder.setItems(items, (dialog, item) -> {
    });

    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
    int textViewId = dialog.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/alertTitle", null, null);
    TextView tv = dialog.findViewById(textViewId); // It always returns null
    if (tv != null) {
        tv.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        tv.setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
}
```

Using below lines I tried but it always returns `null` in `findViewById`,

```
int textViewId = dialog.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/alertTitle", null, null);
TextView tv = dialog.findViewById(textViewId);
```

I also tried using `style` but it only change Title text color,

```
<style name="AppCompatAlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:background">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:headerBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

Comment: you can change via theme

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alert Dialog background theme/Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41331645/alert-dialog-background-theme-color)

Comment: try this, but it uses a custom view for header. but very simple and neat ans.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12813088/6060743

Comment: @SaurabhBhandari, my question is different, I want to change title text background not dialog background.

Comment: @SagarZala in theme add your  text color attribute and for background add background attribute

Comment: @SaurabhBhandari, Using `android:textColor` we can change text color, but how can change title background?

Comment: textColorPrimary used for title text and colorPrimary used for background

Comment: `textColorPrimary` not works, I tried.

Comment: Then you need to set Custom title View in your java file

Comment: Looks like `findViewById()` to find the title doesn't work, `android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle` to change title background color doesn't work. I guess `setCustomTitle()` is only way.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use custom title to your alert dialog:

```
TextView textView = new TextView(context);
textView.setText("Select an option");
textView.setPadding(20, 30, 20, 30);
textView.setTextSize(20F);
textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

final CharSequence[] items = {"Visiting Card", "Prescription Letter"};
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
builder.setCustomTitle(textView);
builder.setItems(items, (dialog, item) -> {
    }).show();
```

[image: Custom Alert Dialog Header]

Comment: I only want to change title text color and background color.

Comment: It will change your title text color

Comment: Yes, but what about title background color?

Comment: Now this is exactly what you wanted.

Comment: My question is without using custom layout, but its is good solution. For now I can use this. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176174/discussion-between-anisuzzaman-babla-and-sagar-zala).

Comment: setPadding takes pixel values, so would be better to take the value from resources with getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.dialog_text_padding). About the size/style I would better use setTextAppearance( android.R.style.TextAppearance_Material_DialogWindowTitle );

Answer (score 4):

You can change everything in the alert dialog:

```
// Title
TextView titleView = new TextView(context);
titleView.setText("Title");
titleView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
titleView.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
titleView.setTextSize(20F);
titleView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
titleView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary));
titleView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorAccent));

AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();

ad.setCustomTitle(titleView);

ad.setCancelable(false);

ad.setMessage("Message");

ad.setButton(Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE,"OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // your code
    }
});

ad.show();

// Message
TextView messageView = ad.findViewById(android.R.id.message);

if (messageView != null) {
    messageView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
}

// Buttons
Button buttonOK = ad.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
buttonOK.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary));
```

Answer (score 4):

[check sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4kEj.jpg)

You can change color of alert dialog title, background and button color by using custom theme.

```
   <style name="CustomDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert"> 
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>
```

android: windowBackground to change background color

colorAccent to change button color

android:textColorPrimary to change Dialog title color

apply this theme to dialog

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.CustomDialogTheme);
```

Comment: No help for `AlertDialog` title.

Answer (score 2):

IMO you call `dialog.show();` before set color so try below code

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        builder.setMessage(message)
        .setTitle(title).setCancelable(false);
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

int textViewId = dialog.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/alertTitle", null, null);
TextView tv = dialog.findViewById(textViewId); // It always returns null
if (tv != null) {
    tv.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    tv.setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));

    }
  dialog.show(); //change here
```

**update**

just try where you set title to alert below line

```
alert.setTitle( Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FF7F27'>Hello World</font>"));
```

Comment: Using style I can change font color, what about background??

Comment: for this try `dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.color.glassblack);` ...

Comment: omik, this changes the whole dialog background to that color. not the title.

Answer (score 1):

I know you don't want this, but using a View is the best way to do this.
With a custom View you can change every Color very easy.

1. Just create a Layout and put your items there (and change the colors)
2. Create a LayoutInflater:`LayoutInflater layoutinflater = getLayoutInflater;`
3. Set a View like: `View view1 = layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.yourlayout, null);`
4. Set `view1` to your builder: `builder.setView(view1);`

#### If you want to use items in the AlertDialog, declare your variables with view1!

Example: `Textview tx = (TextView)view1.findViewById(R.id.textview)`

Comment: No, I don't want to use custom layout.

Comment: @SagarZala Why? It's very easy and you've got more options to customize your AlertDialog

Answer (score 1):

You can set theme:

`new AlertDialog.Builder(this, AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK);`

or you can add `setOnShowListener()` like below:

```
final CharSequence[] items = {" Visiting Card", "Prescription Letter"};
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
            builder.setMessage(message)
            .setTitle(title).setCancelable(false);

builder.setItems(items, (dialog, item) -> {
});

AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
                @Override
                public void onShow(DialogInterface arg0) {
                    int titleId = getResources().getIdentifier("alertTitle", "id", "android");
                    TextView dialogTitle = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(titleId);
                    dialogTitle.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    dialogTitle.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                }
 });
 dialog.show();
```

Comment: `getResources().getIdentifier("alertTitle", "id", "android")` doesn't work. Returns null object.

Answer (score -1):

That's what worked for me, so simple:
my dialog for some reason showed the title background different than the dialog background, so after adding this code, the problem solved.

after dialog show, set setBackgroundDrawable with your color:

```
mDialog.show();

mDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(put here your color));
```

Answer (score -2):

You can change via code as well.

```
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();
Button buttonPositive = dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
buttonPositive.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.green));
Button buttonNegative = dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
buttonNegative.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.red));
```

Hope that helps you.

Comment: I don't want to change button color. I want to change title text and background color.